# How to make a CRUD tree in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, crud

In Vaadin there is a class TreeGridCrud

```
@Route(value = "products", layout = MainView.class)
public class ProductView extends VerticalLayout {

@Autowired
ProductRepository productRepository;

ProductService productService;
public ProductView(ProductService productService) {


  TreeGridCrud productTable = new TreeGridCrud<>(Product.class, productService);
  add(productTable);

}

private void openNewProductFormEditor() {

}



}
```

It gives
java.lang.NullPointerException: Given child item provider may not be null

How can I make a Tree crud table with group rows?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception message, your `productService` is null.